# Coloring a line where macro finds a certain word

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'd like to know if there's a way to do the following thing using VBA:
If the macro finds the word "Total" in the column B, then interior.color of the line where total is would be colored in Blue, and do it for all the "Total" words in the column B.
Note: I have different Totals... it's not only the word "Total"

LIKE THIS (i.e coloring from col A to F)

[image]

I tried with this but it's not working properly and the code is bad...

```
Sub forme_couleur()
Dim myRow As Integer

  myRow = 1

  While Not IsEmpty(Cells(myRow, 2))
    If Cells(myRow, 2).Find(What:="Total") Is Nothing Then
      myRow = myRow + 1
    Else
      Cells(myRow, 2).Find(What:="Total").Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
    End If
    myRow = myRow + 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: take a look at another option using `AutoFilter` in my code below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub ColorMeBlue()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    s = "Total"

    For i = 1 To N
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, 2).Value, s) > 0 Then
            Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To refer to a range using columns by **number**, use:

```
Sub ColorMeBlue2()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    s = "Total"
    Firstcol = 1
    LastCol = 6
    For i = 1 To N
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, 2).Value, s) > 0 Then
            Range(Cells(i, Firstcol), Cells(i, LastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Great thank gary ! And is it possible to use some variables for instead of A and F ? I have to variables that are "FirstCol" and "LastCol" but they are returning numbers, not letters

Comment: @Jean-FIC  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with conditional formatting, but if you must do it with VBA use something like the following:

```
Sub test()

For i = 1 To Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 2), "Total") Then
    With Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another Concept**: You can go with the `AutoFilter` method. Using this method doesn't require any `For` loops, or any `If`s, just use all the cells that passes the `AutoFilter` criteria of `="*Total*"` inside your Range.

```
Sub ColorMeBlue_Filter()

Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String
Dim FirstCol As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim FiltRng As Range

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
s = "Total"

' (just for my testing)
'FirstCol = 1
'LastCol = 6

Range("A1").AutoFilter
Range(Cells(1, FirstCol), Cells(N, LastCol)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*Total*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd

' set FiltRng to only visible cells (that passed the "Total" filter)
Set FiltRng = Range(Cells(2, FirstCol), Cells(N, LastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' modify interior color of all cells at once (one code line)
FiltRng.Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3598756  check the code above, aren't you proud ;)

Comment: You code also colors the header... 
Replace this line: `Set FiltRng = Range(Cells(1, FirstCol), Cells(N, LastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`
with this: `Set FiltRng = Range(Cells(2, FirstCol), Cells(N, LastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`
Also removed this `Operator:=xlAnd` from the AutoFilter` recorded macro line...

Comment: @EEM thanks for the correction, but isn't this a neat and fast trick ?

Comment: `AutoFilter` is very efficient, I use it a lot instead of for-next, however in this particular case I consider `Find` more efficient. I had the intention of including both methods in my answer but you got it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a formula based conditional formatting, using the COUNTIF(a1:f1,"*Total*") function being >0

Answer (score 0):

Using `Range.Find` avoids: looping through each row and the need to get the last row.

Instead of applying `Range.Find` to each row, just apply it to the entire column, no need to check if the cell is empty (see [Range.Find Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx) for additional details)

*Voici votre code révisé:*

Assuming your data is located at `A:F'

```
Sub forme_couleur()
Const kCriteria As String = "Total"
Dim rTrg As Range, s1stFound As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Columns(2)     'change as required
        Set rTrg = .Cells.Find(What:=kCriteria, After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not (rTrg Is Nothing) Then
            s1stFound = rTrg.Address
            Do
                rTrg.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(224, 240, 248)    'RGB(174, 240, 194) give me a green color - changed as required
                Set rTrg = .Cells.FindNext(After:=rTrg)
            Loop Until rTrg.Address = s1stFound
    End If: End With
    End Sub
```